# Matlab Concatenating Row Vectors With A For Loop

Tags: python, matlab, for-loop, vector, concatenation

Here is what I did:

```
w = zeros(1,28);

e = zeros(1,63) + 1;

r = zeros(1,90) + 2;

t = zeros(1,100) + 3;

y = zeros(1,90) + 4;

u = zeros(1,63) + 5;

i = zeros(1,28) + 6;

qa = horzcat(w,e,r,t,y,u,i);

hist(qa,25,0.5)

h = findobj(gca,'Type','patch');

set(h,'FaceColor',[.955 0 0],'EdgeColor','w');
```

I would like to achieve the effect, but it in a more succinct way. This is my attempt:

```
v= zeros(1,28);

for i=2:8
    v(i) = horzcat(v(i-1) + (i-1));
end
```

And the error I receive is "Cell contents assignment to a non-cell array object."

Also, would anyone know what the python equivalent would be, if it is not too much to ask?

Comment: whatever you are doing in the first and second code blocks are totally different things.

Comment: As I said, it was an attempt at reproducing what I did i my first block of code; but, as you say, it wouldn't. So, how could I reproduce what the first block of code does in a more succinct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also achieve this without a `for` loop, albeit somewhat less intiutive. But hey, it's without loops! Besides, it gives you freedom to pick a different set of values.

```
v=[0;1;2;3;4;5;6]; %values
r=[28 63 90 100 90 63 28]; %number of repeats

qa=zeros(sum(r),1);

qa(cumsum([1 r(1:end-1)]))=1;
qa=v(cumsum(qa));
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a cell array to concatenate vectors for which one of the dimensions always remain the same (for example, row or columns, in your case, row).
You can define the sizes in a separate array and then use `for` loop as follows.

```
szArray=[28 63 90 100 90 63 28];
qa=[];

for i=0:length(szArray)-1
   %multiplying by i replicates the addition of a scalar you have done.
   qa=[qa i*ones(1,szArray(i+1)];
end
```

This is still hardcoding. It will only apply to the exact problem you have mentioned above.